# $\mathbb{R}$ is closed under division

Tags: division-algebras

The set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ is closed under division. Does that mean $0$ is also considered?
more specifically, should it be $\mathbb{R}-\{ 0 \}$?
because division by $0$ is not defined.

Comment: you're right, it makes sense for sets

Comment: I frown a bit at asking whether something is "closed under" a certain operation when that operation is undefined. Normally you would already have an operation *fully defined* on a *superset* (say, $-$ on $\mathbb R$) and then you would ask for a *subset* (e.g. $\mathbb N$) whether it is *closed* under that operation . (In this case, if $x,y\in\mathbb N$, does $x-y\in\mathbb N$?) Thus, wherever this formulation comes from, I think it slightly abuses the words "closed under".

Answer (score 2):

The real numbers aren't closed under division unless you don't include zero. So it is like you said: $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ is closed under division since we don't encounter that problem.